# Can't create projects or view any of the project tabs on netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm currently using a Windows 10 OS, I currently have JDK 13, and Netbeans 8.2 version. Whenever I try to create a new project, the pop-up window never seems to open or whenever I try to open the Projects or Files tab it decides not to open. Below is a screenshot on what it looks like currently. I downloaded the Netbeans 8.2 version that comes with Glassfish.[image: Screenshot of NetBeans currently]

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 is old (released October 2016) and is designed to be used with Java 8. Given you are using Java 13, I recommend you use the [latest version](https://netbeans.apache.org/) of NetBeans. Either way, make sure you have a valid Java platform visible to NetBeans (Tools > Java Platforms).

Comment: For more specific troubleshooting, you can see what errors are shown in the log file. Go to Help > About to see the location of the User Directory, and then look in the var/log/ folder for log files. Then [edit] your question to show the relevant error messages.

Comment: Yeah I installed JDK 8 and changed the config of netbeans to have the directory of JDK 8 and it managed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - I had to downgrade back to JDK 8 and change the configurations of netbeans to have JDK 8 as my directory!